# Windows Action Center notification icon says Backup in Progress when no backup is occurring

Tags: windows-8, windows-backup, action-center

How can I get Windows Action Center's little flag in the notification area to stop saying "Backup In Progress" on Windows 8? It's driving me nuts. I disabled the Windows Backup service completely and turned off File Recovery. Nothing that I can tell is using any disk I/O whatsoever, by examining Task Manager's resource monitor. It's just a visual cue that seems totally wrong considering my disk is only using about 50 KB/s of sporadic writes for superfetch etc.

This wouldn't be a problem for me, since I rely on the knowledge that the Backup service is disabled and there's no disk activity, but I am trying to support a more traditional user who relies on visual cues from the operating system and trusts them over low-level observations like "...but the Windows Backup service is disabled!" Therefore this user still thinks that the backup is going on, even after the service is disabled.

Technically, I think this is a bug in Windows 8. It really should not be displaying "Backup in Progress" if ... you know ... a backup, is not, in progress. Which it isn't. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is File History enabled? Maybe that could cause something like this. Edit: Did you mean Recovery = History?

Comment: What about network activity? Could this be part of the built in cloud backup stuff? (TBH I'm not too informed on that so correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: File History is disabled, and yes, File Recovery in my OP = File History.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few solutions present themselves after some googling

One is to bite the bullet and **enable the backup schedule**. The notification now apparently **dissappears in some time** (hrs). `Cypher2Dex` claims, in [this post](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/1/tech-helproom/4083058/backup-in-progress-icon-permanently-in-system-tray/) that this fixed it for him/her, and that it might be because the backup was **disabled** in the **middle of a backup** and it got messed up due to it.

**Alternatively**, you could follow spunk.funk in this forum and **disable backup notifications** from turning up in action center. To do this,

> Right click the Action Center flag by the clock and choose Open Action Center/Change Action Center Settings on the left panel. Under Windows Messages Uncheck the Box Windows Backup.

A third [post](http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=44767) suggests if a backup did happen once, and onto a external disk, maybe the disk was removed "unsafely" or prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click **Action Center**
2. Select **Open Action Center**
3. Select **Change Action Center Settings**
4. Under **Maintenance Messages**, uncheck **Windows Backup**.

Answer (score 0):

It means that maintenance is in progress. Have a look at the action center. Go to "maintenance", then under look under "automatic maintenance". I think that will answer your questons.

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, locate the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup/ActionCenter
```

Delete the key and reboot the machine.  The message "Backup in Progress" will no longer be there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue yesterday. Despite all of the suggestions here and elsewhere suggesting that I should disable settings or notifications -- which really didn't help -- I was able to resolve the problem by running the backup process again.

**After the backup process ran again, the notification disappeared.**

Note that I didn't have to "enable the scheduler" as suggested by [karthik-t](https://superuser.com/users/160502/karthik-t). I just clicked "Back up now."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked!

Until I manually selected a small folder to backup, run backup (which took 2 minutes) and the message disappeared.